# How to interpret chart generated by gbm.perf function?

Tags: r, machine-learning, boosting

I'm new to GBM.Can you help me to understand the interpretation of gbm.perf function?
I used following code in R

`best.iter = gbm.perf(train, method="cv")` & got following chart. I used 3000 tress to generate GBM
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During boosting, simple base-learners are iterively combined to produce the final estimate. This graph shows the performance metric's evolution as the gradient boosting algorithm combines a progressively larger number of base learners.

In particular, in the case of this classification task, the performance metric used in the Bernoulli [deviance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deviance_(statistics)) and the iterations themselves refer to the number of trees (the `n.trees` argument). Smaller deviance values correspond to better performance (simplistically, deviance relates directly to $-2$ times the likelihood estimate for the data's assumed distribution). Notice that you (correctly) specify `method="cv"`; this means that the algorithm evaluates the performance of the ensemble of learners using cross-validation, i.e. by using a random sub-sampling approach. It is vital to do that because otherwise it is extremely prone to over-fit our training set and have poor generalisation of our learner. Finally: the blue dashed line shows what is the optimal number of iterations according to the metric and validation procedure used; i.e. we should use all 3000 available base learners to get the best performance out of the model definition used.

The [`gbm` vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm/vignettes/gbm.pdf) is rather informative one would like to explore this further; Sect. 3.3. "*Estimating the optimal number of iterations*" should rather relevant for what is presented here.